# java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy on servicemix

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to use spring boot to develop a WebService service and publish it in ServiceMix, but I got an Exception like this :

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getMetaAnnotationTypes(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:635)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.glodon.webservice_1.App.start(App.java:22)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2238)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1213)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:507)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

It means some annotation is referencing a class that isn't on the classpath,but how can I konw which class is missed?
my Manifest Headers is :

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1504594453579
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
Built-By: yangez
Bundle-Activator: com.glodon.webservice_1.App
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: webservice_1
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.glodon.webservice_1
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.glodon.webservice_1; uses:="javax.jws, javax.xml.ws, org.apache.cxf.bus.spring, org.osgi.framework, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet, org.springframework.context.annotation"; version="0.0.1"
Import-Package: javax.jws; resolution:=optional, javax.servlet; resolution:=optional, javax.xml.ws; resolution:=optional, org.apache.cxf; resolution:=optional; version="[3.1, 4)", org.apache.cxf.bus.spring; resolution:=optional; version="[3.1, 4)", org.apache.cxf.jaxws; resolution:=optional; version="[3.1, 4)", org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet; resolution:=optional; version="[3.1, 4)", org.osgi.framework; resolution:=optional; version="[1.6, 2)", org.springframework.boot; resolution:=optional, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure; resolution:=optional, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet; resolution:=optional, org.springframework.context; resolution:=optional, org.springframework.context.annotation; resolution:=optional
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.3.0.201609221906
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your imports are `resolution:=optional` which means your bundle will probably always resolve but you will have no guarantee needed classes are available when needed. Like your current situation. Optional resolution is for packages which are truly optional and where your bundle is prepared to deal with the missing types. But if your code must have the types present, then the import of the package of those types is mandatory.

I would suggest you remove the `resolution:=optional` from your imports and see how things go. You may get resolve errors due to missing exporters of a package, but that will tell you what your bundle needs.